# Rotating a 2D Array Matrix with a single string of 'right' or 'left' as a second argument

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to develop a solution to rotating a 2D array by 90 degrees, but the rotating to right or left would be dependent on the second argument of `direction` that is one of my challenges in addition to the fact that it's rotating a 4 by 3 matrix. This is what I have thus far:

```
const solve = (intArray, direction) => {
  const matrix = intArray.slice();
  
  for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < matrix.length; rowIndex+= 1) {
    for (let columnIndex = rowIndex + 1; columnIndex < matrix.length; columnIndex += 1) {
        [
        matrix[columnIndex][rowIndex],
        matrix[rowIndex][columnIndex],
      ] = [
        matrix[rowIndex][columnIndex],
        matrix[columnIndex][rowIndex],
      ];
    }   
  }
  
  for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < matrix.length; rowIndex += 1) {
    for (let columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < matrix.length / 2; columnIndex += 1) {
        [
        matrix[rowIndex][matrix.length - columnIndex - 1],
        matrix[rowIndex][columnIndex],
      ] = [
        matrix[rowIndex][columnIndex],
        matrix[rowIndex][matrix.length - columnIndex - 1],
      ];
    }
  }
  
  return matrix;
};


solve([
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12]
], "right")
```

Comment: When you say "rotate 90 degrees", does it mean that 4 by 3 matrix is going to output a 3 by 4 matrix?

Comment: @KentaNomoto, yes so for the above, the result should look like `[
 [9, 5, 1],
 [10, 6, 2],
 [11, 7, 3],
 [12, 8, 4]
]`

Comment: @KentaNomoto, the second for loop you are adding zeros to those elements in the array. Why? Is it because they have to be zero or null first before being replaced with the actual elements of the rotated matrix?

Comment: That is actually a great point. I added the 0s so that I don't need to perform inserting on the later loop. The line "matrix[(matrix.length - 1) - columnIndex][rowIndex]" or "matrix[columnIndex][(matrix[0].length - 1) - rowIndex]" will give an out of index error if I try to use "=" unless there are spaces for it.  
If I didn't added 0s beforehand, I would have to either loop from backwards at some loops parts, or to insert the values instead of assigning when necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach to this problem. I tried creating a matrix with row columns and column rows of the input matrix. Meaning that 4 by 6 matrix is created from an input of 6 by 4 matrix.

Then, based on the second input, copy the values of the original matrix to the corresponding place to the new matrix.

```
const solve = (intArray, direction) => {
  const matrix = intArray.slice();

  //create a matrix of 0s of column * row of the input matrix. 6*4 matrix will be 4*6 matrix
  let newMatrix = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i += 1){
    newMatrix.push([]);
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix.length; j += 1){
      newMatrix[i].push(0);
    }
  }

  for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < newMatrix.length; rowIndex += 1){
    for (let columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < newMatrix[0].length; columnIndex += 1){
      if (direction == "right"){
        //if right, shift the values clockwise
        newMatrix[rowIndex][columnIndex] = matrix[(matrix.length - 1) - columnIndex][rowIndex]
      }else if (direction == "left"){
        //if left, shift the values anticlockwise
        newMatrix[rowIndex][columnIndex] = matrix[columnIndex][(matrix[0].length - 1) - rowIndex]
      }
    }
  }

  return newMatrix;
};


solve([
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12]
], "left")  // returns [ [ 4, 8, 12 ], [ 3, 7, 11 ], [ 2, 6, 10 ], [ 1, 5, 9 ] ]
            
solve([
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12]
], "right")  // returns [ [ 9, 5, 1 ], [ 10, 6, 2 ], [ 11, 7, 3 ], [ 12, 8, 4 ]
```

There was also a Stack Exchange discussion to a similar problem, so you can check it out if you want to optimize the code. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676441/how-to-rotate-the-positions-of-a-matrix-by-90-degrees

Answer (score 2):

You could take the switched dimensions for creating new arrays and take adjusted indices for the values.

```
positive  given     negative
--------  --------  --------
   3 6      1 2 3      4 1
   2 5      4 5 6      5 2
   1 4                 6 3
```

```js
function rotate(array, positive) {
    var l = array.length,
        k = array[0].length;
    return Array.from(
        { length: k },
        (_, j) => Array.from(
            { length: l },
            (__, i) => array[positive ? i: l - i - 1][positive ? k - j - 1: j]
        )
    );
}

rotate([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], true).map(a => console.log(...a));
console.log('');
rotate([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], false).map(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```